# Quartz .NET scheduler setup

Tags: .net, database, installation, quartz.net

I plan to have an application where there is an installation of Quartz that will run hundreds of thousands of jobs and triggers to update items on a Database.

What is the best server setup for this one?

Can I just run quartz in my Database server?

Or should I have an another application server that will run the jobs and triggers of Quartz? What should be the ideal specs of the server?

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I don't think that will run and I have a serious problem thinking of a scenario where thousands of triggers many ANY sense. I can not imagine Quartz being optimized for this. I suggest sitting down and thinking of a better way to do that.

Comment: Does it mean that Quartz is not suitable for running a lot of triggers?

Comment: No, it mostly mean that I have never come to a scenario where thousands of triggers where not a total failure of the programmer to come up with a decent approach. Thus Quartz s not opimized for this. This sounds a LOT more like a broken architecture than a quartz failure.

Comment: So can you suggest a decent approach for this?

Comment: SImple. Cut it down to less than 100 schedules. Or start explaining why the heck you need thousands. I can nto see into your mind, you know. It looks ridiculous - but then you dont give any explanation why you think you need thousands of schedules.

Comment: Tom take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238228/quartz-net-for-online-game-scheduling . Well anyway I'm trying to come up with a better solution though :)

Comment: Broken design. Have one schedule triggering regularly (every 1 second). Then in the handler method handle everything that is due in this "round". This significantly reduces the number of separate schedules you need. If anything, use the scheduler to schedule "work orders" (tasks) for all due activities. Only one schedule needed.